# bootstrap collapse does not work for multiple rows of cards

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

The button appears, #more div is hidden, but when i click show more the hidden content does not appear. Could this be because of multiple rows? should i add collapse to every card? I am using bootstap4. Code is as follows:

```
<div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Show more
      </button>
    </div>
  <div id="more" class="collapse">

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/10.JPG"  >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/11.JPG" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/7.JPG" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/13.JPG">
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/14.jpg"  >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/15.jpg"  >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/16.jpg" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/17.jpg" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/18.jpg"  >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/19.jpg" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/20.jpg" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/21.jpg" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/22.jpg" alt="Lights" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/23.jpg" alt="Nature" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/24.jpg" alt="Fjords">
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/25.jpg" alt="Fjords">
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/12.JPG" alt="Lights" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/27.jpg" alt="Nature" >
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/28.jpg" alt="Fjords">
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="projectmages/29.jpg" alt="Fjords">
              <div class="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal code fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bootstrap v4.4.1 and the jquery, popper, bootstrap javascript, your code is working fine. The cards are collapse and expand accordingly when the button is clicked.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#more" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Show more
      </button>
</div>
<div id="more" class="collapse">

  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/10.JPG">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/11.JPG">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/7.JPG">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/13.JPG">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/14.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/15.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/16.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/17.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/18.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/19.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/20.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/21.jpg">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/22.jpg" alt="Lights">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/23.jpg" alt="Nature">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/24.jpg" alt="Fjords">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/25.jpg" alt="Fjords">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/12.JPG" alt="Lights">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/27.jpg" alt="Nature">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/28.jpg" alt="Fjords">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="projectmages/29.jpg" alt="Fjords">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```